# ofstream not outputting file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, ofstream

I'm trying to output some arrays to a file "output.txt". I run this code with no errors but no output file seems to be created to the working directory

```
ofstream myfile("output.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        myfile << "t: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            myfile << t[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        myfile << "x_1: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            myfile << x_1[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        myfile << "y_1: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            myfile << y_1[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        myfile << "x_2: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            myfile << x_2[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        myfile << "y_2: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            myfile << y_2[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

What's the problem?

Comment: If `range == 0` (almost) nothing will be written to the file, though the file should be created. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure you're `output.txt` file is being created in the directory you think it is?

Comment: the output should be created and at least the labels "t:" etc. should be written. you are probably looking in the wrong directory. for ex. if you are running from Visual Studio the file will probably be in the solution directory instead of .exe directory. it depends on the current working directory - for ex. >= c++17 you can check the current working dir with `std::filesystem::current_path()` just to be sure

Comment: If the `output.txt` file is created then it might be a problem in `range` value. show us the complete code so that we can help you.